# Calcular primer segundo y tercer lugar de una tabla posiciones

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando una tabla de posiciones de un torneo. Ahora tengo dudas en cómo calcular el primer segundo y tercer lugar usando **Javascript**, estableciendo que el primer lugar obtenga 30 Puntos, el segundo 20 Puntos y por ultimo el 3er lugar que obtenga 10 puntos. Esto mostrarlo en un mensaje o alerta modal.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Genero</th>
      <th>Equipo</th>
      <th>PJ</th>
      <th>PG</th>
      <th>PP</th>
      <th>PE</th>
      <th>GF</th>
      <th>GC</th>
      <th>DFG</th>
      <th>PTS</th>
      <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
      <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td  data-title="PG">1</td>
      <td data-title="PP">1</td>
      <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td  data-title="GF">3</td>
      <td  data-title="GC">4</td>
      <td  data-title="DFG">-1</td>
      <td  data-title="PTS">3</td>
      <td rowspan="3"><input type="submit" class="calcularp"value="Calcular" onclick="calculartp()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
      <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td  data-title="PG">2</td>
      <td data-title="PP">0</td>
      <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td  data-title="GF">7</td>
      <td  data-title="GC">1</td>
      <td  data-title="DFG">6</td>
      <td  data-title="PTS">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
      <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td  data-title="PG">0</td>
      <td data-title="PP">2</td>
      <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td  data-title="GF">1</td>
      <td  data-title="GC">6</td>
      <td  data-title="DFG">-5</td>
      <td  data-title="PTS">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Estaba probando con esta función en Javascript pero no obtengo ningún resultado.

```js
function calculartp(){
  var td = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^="pts"]');
  var mayor = 0;
  var ganador=0;
  for(var i = 0;i<td.length;i++){
    if(mayor<td[i].value){
      ganador = td[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("td").value;
    }
  }
  alert('el ganador es ' + ganador);
}
```

Eh aplicado la funcion de ambos pero tengo la siguiente observacion,tanto como 1,2 y 3 lugar me sale el mismo equipo y con el mismo puntaje.
La data que se muestra en la tabla se obtiene de una Base de datos en MYSQL.
adjunto imagen de lo indicado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero su gentil apoyo con este caso.
saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MEJORAS EN EL CODIGO, solucion** para el problema de buscar el primer, segundo y tercer lugar.

El codigo JavaScript habia que modificarlo para que hiciera la recoleccion de informacion, luego se ordena los datos y finalmente se envia el contenido a un `alert()`.

1) Se cambio la rutina para ordenar el array de objetos por otro codigo.

**Antes:**

```
 arreglo.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.pts < b.pts) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if (a.pts > b.pts) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    // a must be equal to b
                    return 0;
                });
```

**Ahora:**

```
  arreglo.sort(function (a, b){
                    return (b.pts - a.pts)
  });
```

2) Se coloco dentro del `push()` para pts: datos el `parseInt()`

**Ahora el nuevo codigo es el siguiente:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Genero</th>
            <th>Equipo</th>
            <th>PJ</th>
            <th>PG</th>
            <th>PP</th>
            <th>PE</th>
            <th>GF</th>
            <th>GC</th>
            <th>DFG</th>
            <th>PTS</th>
            <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
            <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
            <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
            <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
            <td  data-title="PG">1</td>
            <td data-title="PP">1</td>
            <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
            <td  data-title="GF">3</td>
            <td  data-title="GC">4</td>
            <td  data-title="DFG">-1</td>
            <td  data-title="PTS">3</td>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
            <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
            <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
            <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
            <td  data-title="PG">2</td>
            <td data-title="PP">0</td>
            <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
            <td  data-title="GF">7</td>
            <td  data-title="GC">1</td>
            <td  data-title="DFG">6</td>
            <td  data-title="PTS">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
            <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
            <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
            <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
            <td  data-title="PG">0</td>
            <td data-title="PP">2</td>
            <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
            <td  data-title="GF">1</td>
            <td  data-title="GC">6</td>
            <td  data-title="DFG">-5</td>
            <td  data-title="PTS">0</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" class="calcularp"value="Calcular" onclick="calculartp()">

      <script>
         function calculartp(){       
                // declaracion de variables
                var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");
                var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
                var arreglo= [];
                // crear array objeto con finalista
                for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
                    arreglo.push({"equipo":equipo[i].innerHTML,"pts":parseInt(pts[i].innerHTML)});
                }
                
              console.log(arreglo);

               // nueva rutina para ordenar ganadores
                arreglo.sort(function (a, b){
                    return (b.pts - a.pts)
                });

              console.log(arreglo);
                
                    // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts + '\n';
                    alert(contenido);

       }


      </script>

     
</body>
</html>
```

Este seria ahora el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que sea de ayuda...

Comment: eh aplicado esta función en mi trabajo, pero me olvidé mencionar que la data que se está mostrando se obtiene de una base de datos en mysql, y al aplicarlo me figura en la alerta  que el primero y segundo y tercer lugar  es el equipo rojo con 6 pts.

Comment: coloca dos console.log(arreglo) la primera antes de que se ejecute la funcion ordenar y la otra despues de la ejecucion ordenar, pulsa F12 ve a la consola y si verifica el contenido de las variables arreglo. si la primera no tiene los datos correctos el problema esta en la carga de los elementos. (puede que sea la carga  una carga dinamica) en caso de que el error sea en la seguna, entonces hay que corregir la rutina de ordenamiento.

Comment: eh colocado console.log(arreglo) y  me muestra la siguiente descripcion en la consola:         []
puntaje.js:28 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: tuve que modificar en esta parte:contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts + '\n';
                    alert(contenido);                                                                                        cambiar el numero de arreglo

Comment: quedaria asi,   // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[3].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[3].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[6].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[6].pts + '\n';
                    alert(contenido);

Answer (score 5):

Lo ideal quizá sería agregar clases, pero manteniendo el HTML esta sería una posible solución:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("calcularp")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {

  let tabla = [];


  [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody>tr')].forEach((e) => {
    let puntosEquipo = +e.querySelector('[data-title="PTS"]').innerText;

    let obj = {}
    obj.equipo = e.querySelector('[data-title="Equipo"]').innerText;
    obj.puntos = puntosEquipo;

    tabla.push(obj);

  });

  //const tabla = Object.entries(puntosEquipo);
  tabla = tabla.sort((a, b) => b.puntos - a.puntos);


  alert(`primer puesto ${tabla[0].equipo}. 
  segundo puesto  ${tabla[1].equipo}. 
  tercer puesto ${tabla[2].equipo}.`);

});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Genero</th>
      <th>Equipo</th>
      <th>PJ</th>
      <th>PG</th>
      <th>PP</th>
      <th>PE</th>
      <th>GF</th>
      <th>GC</th>
      <th>DFG</th>
      <th>PTS</th>
      <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
      <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td data-title="PG">1</td>
      <td data-title="PP">1</td>
      <td data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td data-title="GF">3</td>
      <td data-title="GC">4</td>
      <td data-title="DFG">-1</td>
      <td data-title="PTS">20</td>
      <td rowspan="3"><input type="submit" class="calcularp" value="Calcular"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
      <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td data-title="PG">2</td>
      <td data-title="PP">0</td>
      <td data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td data-title="GF">7</td>
      <td data-title="GC">1</td>
      <td data-title="DFG">6</td>
      <td data-title="PTS">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
      <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
      <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
      <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
      <td data-title="PG">0</td>
      <td data-title="PP">2</td>
      <td data-title="PE">0</td>
      <td data-title="GF">1</td>
      <td data-title="GC">6</td>
      <td data-title="DFG">-5</td>
      <td data-title="PTS">30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Básicamnete los datos están dentro de un `tr` dentro de un `tbody` (`tbody>tr`), iteramos sobre cada grupo, y hacemos `[data-title="PTS"]` para obtener los puntos. Cada dato lo ponemos como objeto (`{equipo:"":puntos:""}`) en un array y luego lo ordenamos de mayor a menor con la propiedad `puntos` usando `sort()`.

Comment: eh aplicado esta función en mi trabajo, pero me olvidé mencionar que la data que se está mostrando se obtiene de una base de datos en mysql, y al aplicarlo me figura en la alerta que el primero y segundo y tercer lugar es el equipo rojo con 6 pts